# Android: Order ListView by names from data model

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am trying to order a `ListView` alphabetically.

I have a data model class called `AiringModel()` that has a getter called `getName()`. I need to order the ListView based on the return values from `getName()`.

So far I tried using a `Comparator` on the adapter with a `sort()` like this:

```
final ArrayAdapter<AiringModel> adapter = new TrackingAdapter(
                activity.getSherlockActivity(), resultList);
        //resultList -> List<AiringModel> list
        adapter.sort(new Comparator<AiringModel>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(AiringModel lhs, AiringModel rhs) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
            }
        });
        trackingAdapter = adapter;
        activity.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This doesn't work though, no errors, the `ListView` just stays exactly the same.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

The list sorted perfectly according to logs so I went digging some more and it turns out I was resetting the adapter in another thread, sigh. Thanks for giving me some ideas though, it helped.

Comment: what's 'TrackingAdapter'?

Comment: extends ArrayAdapter<AiringModel> (custom adapter)

Comment: Have you tried sorting the list first then creating the adapter with an already sorted list?

Comment: Good point, let me try that.

Answer (score 3):

Try to call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after you set it into `ListView`.

Comment: I should have probably done that anyway but it didn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak where you are creating adapter etc.?

Comment: Inside an onPostExecute, and the asynctask is called in onCreate()

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak so i though something like this. So create adapter outside of Asyntask(in onCreate method) set it to ListView and in onPostExcute just perform sorting and call notifyDataSetChanged. probably will be better to create own subclass of adapter to get more control around adapter.